# How to access an existing directory in your project without knowing it's path Java

Tags: java, io

I want to write a method that iterates through current files in a directory named "Users". Since different machines have different absolute paths i need a way of accessing this folder without hardcoding the path.

assume I am in the src folder and the Users folder already exists.

```
    public static boolean validUsername(String user) {
        File dir = new File("./Users/");
        File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
        System.out.println(dir);
        System.out.println(directoryListing);
        if (directoryListing != null) {
            for (File child : directoryListing) {
                // Do something with child
                // think child is filename?
                if (user.equals(child.getName())){
                    return false;

                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

whenever i call this method in the main method, the directory listing variable is always null, even if the Users folder has files in it already.

Comment: IDE(s) work differently than you expected. The *easiest* way to do this kind of thing (in my opinion) is to base your path on the user's home folder. In Java that is easy to get in a cross platform way, namely `System.getProperty("user.home")`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can you post a code snippet? Im not sure how to automate a path from each clients home directory to the folder i want to read from.

Comment: `File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.pathSeparator + "abc/foo.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this. There is some of them

1. Put your path in config file
2. Use relative path
3. Use System property variables